# jQuery load to multiple divs

Tags: jquery, load

I have this code

```
$("body").on({
    click: function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var aLink = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#content").load(aLink+" #loader", function(){
          //Callback here
        });
        $("#crumbbar").load(aLink+' .breadcrumbs', function(){
          //Callback here
        });
    }
}, "a");
```

Can this be optimized in such a way that I only have 1 load command?

Comment: I don't think so, you're padding different parameters to load. But I'll be happy if someone else posts up a solution :-)

Comment: I really don't understand this part: `$("body").on({click:function(event){` and than you have: `aLink=$(this).attr('href');` you have a href attribute for your `BODY` element?? And what you mean by: *optimized in such a way that I only have 1 load command?*

Comment: @roko - The `a` at the end means it's a delegated event, it just looks a little different because the events are in a map.

Comment: @adeneo njeh, didn't paid attention to that last line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only do the ajax call once, you would have to use another of jQuery's ajax functions, like `$.get`, which `load()` is a shortcut for:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var aLink = $(this).attr("href");
    $.get(aLink, function(data) {
        $("#content").html($(data).find('#loader'));
        $("#crumbbar").html($(data).find('.breadcrumbs').first())
    });
});
```

Comment: You forgot that he only want to target `a` elements inside of body. I'd go for something like `$(document).on("click", "a", function(e){ ... });` instead :)

Comment: Yes, was meaning to add that without the map, just forgot, thanks!

Comment: Also, I'd cache the selectors for #content and #crumbbar outside of the bind.

Comment: And one last thing. You can access `href` by `this.href` instead of using `attr()`. It's native and alot quicker. I'd do the changes myself, but that would be rude hehe

Comment: `this.href` gets the entire href, including the domain name etc. while the jQuery version gets the actual content of the attribute, so there could be issues with `this.href`. Also, caching the selectors does not really make sense when they are only used once for each click, and the performance gains would be unnoticeable!

Comment: Yeah you're right about `this.href`, but in this case I can't see any problem with getting absolute href since it's loaded with ajax anyways. And regarding the selectors, they aren't only used once? Each click on an anchor will trigger the `.get` which in turn will do the lookups.

Comment: Yes, but looking up elements by ID takes about 0.0000000003 seconds, so it's not really an issue. Neither is using `body` or `document` as the listening element, it does'nt really matter as both contain all the elements.

Comment: Awesome - thank you! :) - @Marcus: this.href worked great also - why is it faster? Can you explain? Thanks.

Comment: @afcdesign Because it's native and does not have to go through the various bells and whistles that jQuery provides ;)

Comment: @Marcus: Ah I see - I can do a little jQuery, but not much javascript - maybe I should take som courses :D

Comment: @adeneo There's really no reason to cut corners in this case, since the more performant code is as easy to use and as much code to write.

Comment: I usually use `this.href` myself, just be aware that if using relative URL's, or links with just the hash etc. you'll have issues, and that's why `href` is the one attribute I normally don't change when answering questions, you never know what the OP uses for links. Otherwise, `this.id` etc does exactly the same as the jQuery version only faster. The big performance gain here is doing the ajax call once instead of twice, and that's something that is actually noticeable.

Comment: @afcdesign This is a problem with the jQuery community, imo. Too many walk the path to learn jQuery but have no clue about pure JavaScript. Since jQuery is built with JavaScript, it helps a lot to know the underlying parts

Comment: @adeneo True, but if I wanted to use the hash I'd go with `this.hash`:D