# jQuery - Load multiple elements into more than one location

Tags: jquery

I'm currently loading in several bits of information from a single page into a `div` (`$this`)

```
$this.load( $categoryUrl + ' ' + '.product:nth-child(' + (i + 1)+ ') .productImage, '
            + '.product:nth-child(' + (i + 1)+ ') .productTitle, ' 
            + '.product:nth-child(' + (i + 1)+ ') .productPrice',
   function() {
    // Function
   });
```

Is there a way to add these loaded elements into individual containers without making multiple calls?

**So for example:**

- `.productImage` is added to `#prdImg`
- `.productTitle` is added to `#prdTitle`
- `.productPrice` is added to `#prdPrice`

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to [jQuery load to multiple divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340334/jquery-load-to-multiple-divs)

Comment: Download the data via AJAX, then allocate the various elements as part of the success function.